# Capture text in quotes immediately before keyword

Tags: regex

I have an input stream that looks like this:

`"ignore this" blah "ignore this" blah "capture this" keyword "ignore this" blah`

I want to capture `capture this`, i.e. the text in quotes before `keyword`.

I tried the regex `(?:\"(.*)\" )(?=keyword)`, but this captures everything up to the quotation mark before `keyword`. How would I capture the text in quotes directly before `keyword`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pattern `(?:\"(.*)\" )(?=keyword)` matches the first `"` and then matches the last occurrence where a double quote followed by a space is followed by `keyword` because the dot also matches a double quote.

Note that in the pattern the non capturing group `(?:` can be omitted and the `"` does not have to be escaped.

You could use a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) instead to match any character except a `"`

The value is in the first capturing group.

```
"([^"]+)"(?= keyword)
```

**Explanation**

- `"` Match literally
- `(` Capturing group

  - `[^"]+` Match 1+ times any char except `"`
- `)` Close group
- `"(?= keyword)` Match  `"` and assert what is directly to the right is a space and `keyword`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/8jrY5r/1)

An example using Javascript

```js
const regex = /"([^"]+)"(?= keyword)/g;
const str = `"ignore this" blah "ignore this" blah "capture this" keyword "ignore this" blah`;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
  if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
    regex.lastIndex++;
  }
  console.log(m[1]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using lookaround assertions

```js
var input = `"ignore this" blah "ignore this" blah "capture this" keyword "ignore this" blah`;
var result = /(?<=\")[A-Za-z0-9\ ]*(?=\" keyword)/i.exec(input)
console.log(result);
```

Here `(?<=\")` looks for content that follows `"` and `(?=\" keyword)` looks for content that is followed by `" keyword`.

More about Lookahead and Lookbehind Zero-Length Assertions here:
https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Answer (score 0):

Your string to be captured or returned as a result is in between double quotes followed by a specific keyword. simply find that pattern that matches `"` followed by anything that is not `"` then followed by `" keyword`.

```js
var input = `"ignore this" blah "ignore this" blah "capture this" keyword "ignore this" blah`;
var result = /(?=\")?[^"]+(?=\"\s*keyword)/i.exec(input)
console.log(result);
```